# How to localize some specifics missing expressions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, devise, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin which use devise. Some words still displays in english. I have many yml files for i18n (fr, rails_admin.fr, devise.fr). Is there a quick way to find what yml [tree] I have to put in one of those to i18n these missing expressions ?

Comment: Devise 2.0 (which is just released) does internationalization much better, check https://github.com/plataformatec/devise under the I18n section, which also has a link to some examples.  Not sure about rails_admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly all RailsAdmin keys are namespaced with :admin.

Nearly all Devise keys are namespaced with :devise.

Rest would be Rails'.

And eventually it doesn't really matter, you can add them anywhere, and I suggest you put them in a custom project file to keep your libraries' i18n easily updatable.

Comment: I post on SO not to bother you but you are everywhere ! On the signup page sign_in sign_up and forgot_your_password? are not localized...How can I guess since they are not grouped with email and password which are indented under activerecords-user

Comment: I get it. You are supposed to override templates, there is no i18n in Devise's views: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb